# How To Create A WPF Doughnut Chart In .NET 4.5?

Tags: wpf, charts

I need to draw doughnut chart under .net 4.0 but i cannot find any useful library. Metro ui and other need only .net 4.5. I do not want to make custom control. Can you suggest some library?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy with Live Charts https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

it is a new library I started because alternatives right now were not what I needed, maybe it helps you too

```
<liveCharts:PieChart Name="Chart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <liveCharts:PieChart.Series>
            <liveCharts:PieSeries Title="Maria" PrimaryValues="15, 10, 40, 55" 
                                 Labels="Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 4"></liveCharts:PieSeries>
        </liveCharts:PieChart.Series>
        <liveCharts:PieChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <liveCharts:Axis Title="Sold Items"></liveCharts:Axis>
        </liveCharts:PieChart.PrimaryAxis>
    </liveCharts:PieChart>
```

[image]